# dependency errors after installing hedgewars

Tags: package-management

I was installing Hedgewars game on my Ubuntu and then something happened. I don't remember. All I know is I can't remove or install anything.

There is a red icon and when I click it it says Broken Count > 0. When I open software center and click repair, this appears:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 128308 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking hedgewars-data (from .../hedgewars-data_0.9.17-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: invalid stored block lengths'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/hedgewars-data_0.9.17-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./usr/share/games/hedgewars/Data/Forts/WoodR.png'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/hedgewars-data_0.9.17-1_all.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hedgewars:
 hedgewars depends on hedgewars-data (>= 0.9.17); however:
  Package hedgewars-data is not installed.
dpkg: error processing hedgewars (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I am guessing there is something wrong with Hedgewars game.  And also I tried using terminal as they told me on the net it did not work. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then finally `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: it did not work..may be i'll re intstall the OS